# How to convert a javascript date string to another format?

Tags: javascript

I have a string "26-08-2016" and I want to convert it to "2016-08-26". I prefer when possible to do this using the date object. But I am afraid some regex solution is only available?

Comment: `"26-08-2016".split('-').reverse().join('-')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
var date = "26-08-2016";


var newdate = date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
```

Input : 26-08-2016

Output : 2016-08-26

Answer (score 1):

Did you alredy try to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

```
var mydate = moment("26-08-2016" , "DD-MM-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Comment: No but this looks awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The `Date`object does expose an API which allows you to get certain values from the object such as date, month, hour, and timezone, which can be used to format a date string.

Simple formatting example using `Date` object methods.

```
var date = new Date();

var output = [date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, date.getDate()].join('-'); 

console.log( output ); //2016-8-26
```

The better way is probably to write a formatting function like so:

```
function formatDate(now) {
   var year = now.getFullYear();
   var month = now.getMonth()+1;
   var date = now.getDate();

   //Add '0' to month if less than 10
   month = (month.toString().length < 2)
      ? "0"+month.toString()
      : month;

   return [year, month, date].join('-');
   //return `${year}-${month}-${date}`; if you're using ES6
}

var now = new Date();

console.log(
   formatDate(now)
); // 2016-08-26
```

All available methods are found here at mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
montharray = [01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12];
var final_date = new Date("26-08-2016");     
var month_of_date = montharray[final_date.getMonth()];
final_date = final_date.getFullYear() + "-" + month_of_date + "-" + final_date.getDate();
```